# Is it necessary to update major API version when adding new field in response JSON (HTTP GET)?

Tags: javascript, java, python, c#, api

For example, I created API 1.0.0:

HTTP GET /getInfo without parameters.

Response:

```
{
    "info1": "..."
}
```

After release 1.0.0 I want to add new field:

```
{
    "info1": "...",
    "info2": "..."
}
```

1) I don't know who are API's clients. But it is possible(in theory) that they use not flexible deserialization/serialization and they will have problems. Is it real cases? Is it dangerous for clients?

2) Need I upgrade API version to 2.0.0 in that case? Or it will be 1.1.0?

3) Similar question about HTTP POST and its body with new field.

Comment: Which programming language is most relevant to your question?

Comment: Server language is C#. But I don't know who are API's clients (any language).

Comment: I would suggest thinking of it in a way that someone else changes the end-point responses you used in your app and breaks your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest thinking in the frame of compatibility. If your clients will have to rewrite code because you will break them (for example for missing properties), you will need to change the version. This is also letting everyone know something significant changed.

P.S. You should probably keep the old versions of the end-point, if possible or notify them ahead of time and (via response - maybe obsolete) that you will be changing things for them.

Comment: It is impossible to check all clients. Thus, solution is keep old and new version. But I hoped that exists some better.

Answer (score 4):

That's generally not considered a breaking change, so no, a major version change is probably not needed. That will still be backwards compatible because old clients can just ignore those fields when they're deserializing the JSON. (Most deserializers, such as Newtonsoft in C#, will already ignore any extra fields automatically, so no code change is required).

If you removed fields, added new required parameters, etc., then you probably would need to because that would be potentially breaking.

Comment: I know about C# Newtonsoft, but I don't know about other implementations.